# Solving an ODE using the exact method with integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm helping a student out with solving an ODE using the exact equation method.
$$y'=\frac{2x-y^2}{y-2xy}$$
or
$$y^2-2x+(y-2xy)y'=0$$
I get partial derivatives that differ by a sign, $\pm2y$, so I attempt to find an integrating factor that's a function of $x$:
$$\mu(x)=\int\frac{2y-(-2y)}{y-2xy}\,dx=-2\ln(1-2x)$$
However, distributing $\mu$ gives me partial derivatives that don't match up. If we let
$$\mu(x)(y^2-2x)+\mu(x)(y-2xy)y'=M(x,y)+N(x,y)\,y'=0$$
then I get
$$\begin{cases}\dfrac{\partial M}{\partial y}=-4y\ln(1-2x)\\\\
\dfrac{\partial N}{\partial x}=4y+4y\ln(1-2x)\end{cases}$$
Did I make a computational mistake somewhere along the line?

Comment: For making life easier, you could start defining $y=\sqrt z$ which makes the differential equation $(2 x-1) z'-2 z+4 x=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have $$\frac{d\mu}{\mu} = \frac{4dx}{1 - 2x}$$ giving you $$\mu = \frac{1}{(1-2x)^2}$$  with this you will have $$\frac{y^2 - 2x}{(1 -2x)^2} dx + \frac{y - 2xy}{(1-2x)^2} dy = 0 = Mdx + Ndy$$  now $$M_y = \frac{2y}{(1-2x)^2}, N_x = \frac{2y}{(1-2x)^2}. $$

Comment: Ah yes, silly me, I forgot about the exponential part... Thanks